# NSMutableArray new with Protocol type

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

1. How do I get rid of the warning and not use `[@[] mutableCopy]`:

> //Incompatible pointer types assigning to
>   'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSMutableArray *'

```
@protocol Coordinatorable <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UINavigationController *presenter;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSMutableArray<Coordinatorable>*childCoordinators;

@end


self.childCoordinators = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray<Coordinatorable> *' from 'NSMutableArray *'
self.childCoordinators = [@[] mutableCopy]; //works without issue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the cause of your issue is in how you declare your property. The line:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSMutableArray<Coordinatorable>*childCoordinators;
```

should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSMutableArray<id<Coordinatorable>>*childCoordinators;
```

The use of `id<SomeeProtocol>` is what is needed when referencing objects that conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get rid of the warning and not use [@[] mutableCopy]:

Cast the result:

```
self.childCoordinators = (NSMutableArray<Coordinatorable>*)[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```